# Problema com interfaces no Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estou fazendo uma função para retornar um objeto, e estou dizendo que essa função irá retornar uma interface do tipo `ICreditAndCreditCard`

a inteface foi declarada da seguinte maneira.

```js
export interface ICreditAndCreditCard extends ICredit {
  creditCard: ICreditCard;
}
```

E a interface `ICredit` que ela extende esta da seguinte maneira.

```js
export interface ICredit extends IPaymentBody {
  customerAccount: {
    value: string;
  };
}
```

O problema que quando tento fazer minha função retornar esse objeto obtenho o seguinte erro no Typescript.

[image: Erro]

```js
formatCreditAndCreditCard(credit): ICreditAndCreditCard {
      return {
        mode: credit?.mode ?? SHAPE_CREDIT_AND_CREDITCARD.mode,
        name: credit?.name ?? SHAPE_CREDIT_AND_CREDITCARD.name,
        customerAccount: {
          value:
            credit?.customerAccount?.value ?? SHAPE_CREDIT_AND_CREDITCARD.customerAccount.value,
        },
        creditCard: this.formatCredit(credit) ?? SHAPE_CREDIT_AND_CREDITCARD.creditCard,
      };
    }
```

A Interface `IPaymentBody`

```js
export interface IPaymentBody {
  mode: string;
  name: string;
}
```

A função `formatCreditCard()` e seu tipo de retorno

```js
  formatCreditCard(card): ICreditCard {
    return {
      mode: card?.mode ?? SHAPE_CREDITCARD.mode,
      name: card?.name ?? SHAPE_CREDITCARD.name,
      expiryMonth: card?.expiryMonth ?? SHAPE_CREDITCARD.expiryMonth,
      expiryYear: card?.expiryYear ?? SHAPE_CREDITCARD.expiryYear,
      type: {
        code: card?.type?.code ?? SHAPE_CREDITCARD.type.code,
        name: card?.type?.name ?? SHAPE_CREDITCARD.type.name,
      },
      number: card?.number ?? SHAPE_CREDITCARD.number,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Eu acho que estão faltando dados na sua pergunta. Eu não fui capaz de entendê-la ao ponto de _tentar_ dar uma resposta. Talvez valha a pena a **[edit]**? :)

Comment: Pode inserir a interface IPaymentBody? E qual o tipo de retorno de `this.formatCredit`?

Comment: @SamirBraga adicionei

Comment: @LuizFelipe Como poderia melhorar ? acho que agora que editei com mais informações ficou mais claro,

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti, o trecho `creditCard: this.formatCredit(credit)` não deveria ser `creditCard: this.formatCreditCard(credit)`?

Comment: @SamirBraga Obrigado cara, era isso mesmo, falha minha kkkkkkk